WSO2 Identity Server (wso2is-6.1.0) - Default Scope Not Returned in Token Response
I'm using wso2is-6.1.0 and when I invoke the token endpoint with the password grant type without a scope, the default scope is not returned in the response.
{
    "access_token": "<access_token>",
    "refresh_token": "<refresh_token>",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 3542
}

However, it is observed that in the previous versions (5.11.0), the token response returns the scope as default.
{
    "access_token": "<access_token>",
    "refresh_token": "<refresh_token>",
    "scope": "default",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 3542
}

Is the default scope deprecated in the token response wso2is-6.1.0? Any guide on how to enable it properly?
Thanks in advance.

There is no such behavior change observed between IS-5.11.0 vs IS-6.1.0. In both versions, if the token is requested without any scope, no scope attribute in the token response.
As per the APIM docs https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.2.0/design/api-security/oauth2/oauth2-scopes/fine-grained-access-control-with-oauth-scopes/#:~:text=By%20default%20in%20WSO2%20API%2DM%2C%20if%20no%20scopes%20are%20requested%20or%20if%20none%20of%20requested%20scopes%20are%20allowed%2C%20the%20token%20will%20be%20issued%20with%20default%20scope.
By default in WSO2 API-M, if no scopes are requested or if none of requested scopes are allowed, the token will be issued with default scope.


This should be an altered behavior in APIM. Have you changed the APIM version/ or enable/disable any configurations related to RBAC scope validation?

hi @Anuradha thanks for the response. This is a setup where the IS has been used as the resident key manager to the APIM. In the previous versions (4.1.0 - 5.11.0) the token response returned default as the scope when no scopes were passed in the token request. Also, I have not enabled/disabled any configurations related to RBAC scope validation.

In previous case, what is the Token endpoint that you have used to get an Access Token? Also, have you configured the IS as the Resident Key Manager as instructed in this-1 or as this-2. As @Anuradha mentioned, the default scope is provided by the API Manager itself, and the behaviour of WSO2 IS has not been changed. Please check the APIM configurations and update

@Athiththan I used the default token endpoint to invoke the token request, https://localhost:9444/oauth2/token and I referred this documentation to setup the IS as a Key Manager to the APIM. https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/distributed-deployment/configuring-wso2-identity-server-as-a-key-manager/
